# How to overcome the regex depth limitation in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, sas

I'm trying to use rather and convoluted regular expressions. 
Checking my results, I saw that some of my longer compiled patterns were cut short - specifically to the length of 200.

That piqued my interest and I [found](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/dfdmstudio/2.5/dmpdmsug/Content/dfU_Cstm_RegEx_16003.html) that 200 is the depth limit in SAS:

> The maximum number of capturing subpatterns is 65535, and the maximum
>   depth of nesting of all subpatterns, both capturing and non-capturing,
>   is 200.

I was unable to find a quote confirming that this is the case in python, but it would seem so based on my experience - and it may be logical to assume that the fact that this exact numerical limitation exists at the SAS regex engine points that some default cap exists in python as well.

Were is this cap defined? 
And how can I overcome it, and define my own cap?
I was unable to find this in the python-3 documentation.

An example:

```
import re
a="""'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\ \\-\\ AAAAAAA\\ AAAAAAAAAAAA\\ AAAAAAA\\ AAAA\\ AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\=".*"\\,\\ AAAAAAAAAA\\="AAAAAAAAAA\\:\\ \'AAAAAAAAAAA0\'\\,\\ AAA\\:\\ \'.*\'\\,\\ AAAAAAA.*AAAAAAA.*CCCC\\:\\ \'BBBBBBBBBBBBB\'\\,\\ BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\\:\\ \'\'\\,\\ BBBBB\\:\\ \'\'\\,\\ BBBBBBB\\:\\ \'BBBBBBBBBBB\'\''
"""
b=re.compile(a)
print (a)
print (b)
```

Prints:

```
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\ \-\ AAAAAAA\ AAAAAAAAAAAA\ AAAAAAA\ AAAA\ AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\=".*"\,\ AAAAAAAAAA\="AAAAAAAAAA\:\ 'AAAAAAAAAAA0'\,\ AAA\:\ '.*'\,\ AAAAAAA.*AAAAAAA.*CCCC\:\ 'BBBBBBBBBBBBB'\,\ BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\:\ ''\,\ BBBBB\:\ ''\,\ BBBBBBB\:\ 'BBBBBBBBBBB'''
```

and

```
re.compile('\'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\ \\-\\ AAAAAAA\\ AAAAAAAAAAAA\\ AAAAAAA\\ AAAA\\ AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\=".*"\\,\\ AAAAAAAAAA\\="AAAAAAAAAA\\:\\ \'AAAAAAAAAAA0\'\\,\\ AAA\\:\\ \'.*\'\\,\\ AAAAAAA.*AAAAAAA.*CCCC\\:\\)
```

The regex is cut right after the "C"s in the example, before the "B"s.

The size of the inside of the compiled regex,

```
'\'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\ \\-\\ AAAAAAA\\ AAAAAAAAAAAA\\ AAAAAAA\\ AAAA\\ AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\=".*"\\,\\ AAAAAAAAAA\\="AAAAAAAAAA\\:\\ \'AAAAAAAAAAA0\'\\,\\ AAA\\:\\ \'.*\'\\,\\ AAAAAAA.*AAAAAAA.*CCCC\\:\\
```

Is exactly 200.

Post-answer edit: as user2357112 wrote, matching is unchanged.

```
import re
a="""'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA22 22-22 AAAAAAA22 AAAAAAAAAAAA22 AAAAAAA22 AAAA22 AAAAAAAAAAAAAA22=".*"22,22 AAAAAAAAAA22="AAAAAAAAAA22:22 2'AAAAAAAAAAA02'22,22 AAA22:22 2'.*2'22,22 AAAAAAA.*AAAAAAA.*CCCC22:22 2'BBBBBBBBBBBBB2'22,22 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB22:22 2'2'22,22 BBBBB22:22 2'2'22,22 BBBBBBB22:22 2'BBBBBBBBBBB2'2''
"""
b=re.compile(a)

x="""'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA22 22-22 AAAAAAA22 AAAAAAAAAAAA22 AAAAAAA22 AAAA22 AAAAAAAAAAAAAA22="777"22,22 AAAAAAAAAA22="AAAAAAAAAA22:22 2'AAAAAAAAAAA02'22,22 AAA22:22 2'7772'22,22 AAAAAAA777AAAAAAA777CCCC22:22 2'BBBBBBBBBBBBB2'22,22 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB22:22 2'2'22,22 BBBBB22:22 2'2'22,22 BBBBBBB22:22 2'BBBBBBBBBBB2'2''
"""

y="""'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA22 22-22 AAAAAAA22 AAAAAAAAAAAA22 AAAAAAA22 AAAA22 AAAAAAAAAAAAAA22="777"22,22 AAAAAAAAAA22="AAAAAAAAAA22:22 2'AAAAAAAAAAA02'22,22 AAA22:22 2'7772'22,22 AAAAAAA777AAAAAAA777CCCC22:22 2'BBBBBBBBBBBBB2'22,22 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB22:22 2'2'22,22 BBBBB22:22 2'2'22,22 BBBBBBB22:22 2'BBBBBBBBBDD2'2''
"""

if (b.fullmatch(x)):
    print ("x matched!")

if (b.fullmatch(y)):
    print ("y matched!")
```

This indeed matches only `x` and not `y`, even if the difference between them is not the part displayed when printing out the regex.

Comment: That seems like it could just be a problem with the `__repr__`. Have you  checked `b.pattern`?

Comment: Indeed, the problem is only with __repr__, as you can see from the post-answer edit based on your response below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an artifact of the pattern object's [`__repr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Modules/_sre.c#L1303), which truncates the `repr` of the underlying pattern string to 200 characters for some reason:

```
result = PyUnicode_FromFormat("re.compile(%.200R)", obj->pattern);
```

This doesn't affect matching. There is no 200-character limit to overcome.

Comment: The "length of returned variable" for some functions is 200, such as `tranwrd`, and will be applied as the pdv variable length if not previously set within a data step.  So perhaps the variable is set based on a function call, or simply the innards of the studio product or engine implementation sets then length to $200.

Comment: @Richard: Are you talking about SAS? I don't see a `tranwrd` in the CPython source code, but I get a bunch of SAS hits for `tranwrd` on Google. The CPython `re` implementation probably has limits somewhere, but whatever they are, I don't know them.

Comment: I was basing my comment on that the documentation link was to SAS product data flux and further guessing somewhere within that, the implementation limit arose due to some data step processing -- all speculation.